# cohomology ring of cross-section space of one-point compactification of tangent bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, spectral-sequences, fibre-bundles, fibration

Let $M$ be an $m$-manifold whose cohomology is known. Let $TM$ be the tangent bundle of $M$ and $\xi$ be the fibre-wise one-point compactification of $TM$. Then $\xi$ is a $m$-sphere bundle over $M$. Let $\Gamma(\xi)$ be the space of cross-sections  of $\xi$ with compact open topology.

**Question:** How to compute the cohomology ring 
$$
H^*(\Gamma(\xi);\mathbb{Z}_2)?
$$

My attempt: I want to construct fibrations and use Serre spectral sequence. But the fibration
$$
S^m\to E\xi\to M
$$
only concerns the space $E\xi$, but not $\Gamma(\xi)$. Moreover, could the Serre spectral sequence give the explicit ring structure of 
$$
H^*(\Gamma(\xi);\mathbb{Z}_2)
$$ 
completely, but not partial information about the cohomology?

Comment: I think your best bet is computing this using nonabelian Poincaré duality (at least if you're willing to stick with compact manifolds or compactly supported sections). A good reference is http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5522v4.pdf